# Designing a WFS service Client

Tags: c++, object-oriented

The Driver Code that needs to be encapsulated in interfaces is shown next:

```
    OGRDataSource *m_wfs_t;

    m_wfs_t = OGRSFDriverRegistrar::Open("WFS:http://192.168.139.129/cgi-bin/tinyows.exe",true);

    OGRSFDriver*driver = m_dataset->GetDriver();
    std::cout<<driver->GetName();

    OGRLayer *poLayer; 
    poLayer = m_wfs_t->GetLayerByName("tows:frida");


    OGRFeature *poFeature;        


    poFeature = OGRFeature::CreateFeature( poLayer->GetLayerDefn() );

    poFeature->SetField("gfname","ahmed");

    OGRLinearRing ring1, ring2;
    OGRMultiPolygon multi;

    OGRPolygon poly1, poly2;


    ring1.addPoint(1116651.439379124, 637392.6969887456);
    ring1.addPoint(1188804.0108498496, 652655.7409537067);
    ring1.addPoint(1226730.3625203592, 634155.0816022386);
    ring1.addPoint(1281307.30760719, 636467.6640211721);
    ring1.closeRings();
    poly1.addRing(&ring1);


    ring2.addPoint(1179553.6811741155, 647105.5431482664);
    ring2.addPoint(1179553.6811741155, 626292.3013778647);
    ring2.addPoint(1194354.20865529, 626292.3013778647);
    ring2.addPoint(1194354.20865529, 647105.5431482664);
    ring2.addPoint(1179553.6811741155, 647105.5431482664);
    poly2.addRing(&ring2);

    multi.addGeometry(&poly1);
    multi.addGeometry(&poly2);

    poFeature->SetGeometry(&multi);

    if( poLayer->CreateFeature( poFeature ) != OGRERR_NONE ) 

    {
        std::cout <<"error creating a feature"<<endl;

    }

    OGRFeature::DestroyFeature( poFeature );


    // Declare an object to refer to Layers returned from the WFS
    OGRLayer  *Layer;

    int cnt = m_wfs_t->GetLayerCount();
    cnt--;
    while(cnt >= 0 )
    {
        Layer = m_dataset->GetLayer(cnt--);

        // Declare variable for reading the features from a WFS layer
        OGRFeature *Feature;

        // Reset Reading (Although not necessary now because it hasnt been read yet, this is good practice before reading WFS data)
        Layer->ResetReading();

        while( (Feature = Layer->GetNextFeature()) != NULL )
        {
            // Variable initialised to contain the definitions of all of the fileds in the WFS Layer
            OGRFeatureDefn *FeatureDefinition = Layer->GetLayerDefn();

            for( int i = 0; i < FeatureDefinition->GetFieldCount(); i++ )
            {
                // Variable initialised to contain field data at the current index of i
                OGRFieldDefn *FieldDefinition = FeatureDefinition->GetFieldDefn(i);

                if(FieldDefinition->GetType() == OFTInteger)
                {
                    std::cout << Feature->GetFieldAsInteger(i) << ",";
                }
                else if(FieldDefinition->GetType() == OFTReal)
                {
                    std::cout << Feature->GetFieldAsDouble(i) << ",";
                }
                else if( FieldDefinition->GetType() == OFTString )
                {
                    std::cout << Feature->GetFieldAsString(i) << ",";
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << Feature->GetFieldAsString(i) << ",";
                }
            }

            // Variable initialised to contain Geometry point data for the field at the current index of i
            OGRGeometry *Geometry = Feature->GetGeometryRef();


            if(Geometry != NULL && wkbFlatten(Geometry->getGeometryType()) == wkbPoint)
            {
                OGRPoint *Point = (OGRPoint *) Geometry;

                // Maybe need to limit the number of decimal places for X and Y coordinates to 2-3
                std::cout << Point->getX() << "," << Point->getY() << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "No Point Geometry" << std::endl;
            }
            OGRFeature::DestroyFeature( Feature );
        }

    }




    OGRDataSource::DestroyDataSource( m_dataset );
```

Interfaces that needs to encapsulate the above code :

```
class Area
{
public:
  Area(){}
  ~Area(){}
private:
  string m_Id; 
};


class IData
{

private: 
    OGRLayer * m_Layer;
public:
    ~IData() {}
    IData(OGRLayer *layer)
    {
        m_Layer = layer;
    }

    OGRLayer* getLayer();


};

OGRLayer* IData::getLayer()
{
    return m_Layer;
}



class Areas 
{
public:
     Areas(){}
     Areas(std::shared_ptr<IData> data);
     vector<Area>  getAreas();
     ~Areas(){}
 private:
     std::shared_ptr<IData> m_Data;
     vector<Area> m_Areas;
};


Areas::Areas(std::shared_ptr<IData> data)
{
   m_Data = data;
}

vector<Area> Areas::getAreas()
{ 

    if(m_Data == nullptr)
    return vector<Area>();

    // Declare variable for reading the features from a WFS layer
    OGRFeature *Feature;

    // Reset Reading (Although not necessary now because it hasnt been read yet, this is good practice before reading WFS data)
    m_Data->getLayer()->ResetReading();

    while ((Feature = m_Data->getLayer()->GetNextFeature()) != NULL)
    {
        // Variable initialised to contain the definitions of all of the fileds in the WFS Layer
        OGRFeatureDefn *FeatureDefinition = m_Data->getLayer()->GetLayerDefn();

        for (int i = 0; i < FeatureDefinition->GetFieldCount(); i++)
        {
            // Variable initialised to contain field data at the current index of i
            OGRFieldDefn *FieldDefinition = FeatureDefinition->GetFieldDefn(i);

            if (FieldDefinition->GetType() == OFTInteger)
            {
                std::cout << Feature->GetFieldAsInteger(i) << ",";
            }
            else if (FieldDefinition->GetType() == OFTReal)
            {
                std::cout << Feature->GetFieldAsDouble(i) << ",";
            }
            else if (FieldDefinition->GetType() == OFTString)
            {
                std::cout << Feature->GetFieldAsString(i) << ",";
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << Feature->GetFieldAsString(i) << ",";
            }
        }

        // Variable initialised to contain Geometry point data for the field at the current index of i
        OGRGeometry *Geometry = Feature->GetGeometryRef();


        if (Geometry != NULL && wkbFlatten(Geometry->getGeometryType()) == wkbPoint)
        {
            OGRPoint *Point = (OGRPoint *)Geometry;

            // Maybe need to limit the number of decimal places for X and Y coordinates to 2-3
            std::cout << Point->getX() << "," << Point->getY() << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "No Point Geometry" << std::endl;
        }
        OGRFeature::DestroyFeature(Feature);
    }

}


struct IConnection
{
    virtual std::shared_ptr<IData>  QueryLayer(string layer) = 0;
    virtual int                     Write(IData *data) = 0;
    virtual void                    Release() = 0;
    IConnection() {}
    virtual ~IConnection() {}
};

struct ImplIConnection : public IConnection
{
    OGRDataSource *m_wfs_t;
public:
    ImplIConnection(OGRDataSource *dataset)
    {
        m_wfs_t = dataset;
    }
    ~ImplIConnection() {}
private:

    std::shared_ptr<IData>  QueryLayer(string data);
    int                     Write(IData *data);
    void                    Release();

};

std::shared_ptr<IData> ImplIConnection::QueryLayer(string layerName)
{
    OGRLayer  *Layer = m_wfs_t->GetLayerByName(layerName.c_str());
    if (Layer == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }


    std::shared_ptr<IData> data(new IData(Layer));

    return data;
}


int ImplIConnection::Write(IData *data)
{

    return 0;
}



void ImplIConnection::Release()
{


}



struct IMapServer
{
    virtual std::shared_ptr<IConnection>           OpenConnection(string url) = 0;
    virtual void                                   Release() = 0;
    IMapServer() {}
    virtual ~IMapServer() {}

};

struct ImplMapServer : public IMapServer
{

private:
    OGRDataSource *m_wfs_t;
public:
    ImplMapServer() {}
    ~ImplMapServer()
    {
        OGRDataSource::DestroyDataSource(m_wfs_t);
    }
    void Init(void);
    std::shared_ptr<IConnection>     OpenConnection(string url);
    void                             Release() {};
};


std::shared_ptr<IConnection>  ImplMapServer::OpenConnection(string url)
{
    m_wfs_t = OGRSFDriverRegistrar::Open(url.c_str(), true);

    if (m_wfs_t == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<ImplIConnection> connection(new ImplIConnection(m_wfs_t));

    return connection;
}

void ImplMapServer::Init(void)
{
    CPLSetConfigOption("CPL_DEBUG", "ON");
    GDALAllRegister();
    OGRRegisterAll();
}
```

I would like to know how do I get an IConnection from OpenConnection(url);

Also how would I populate the data that I get from the GDAL Library and populate it to my interfaces.

I'm looking for a proper design and how would I implement those interfaces.

Note also how about the Client that uses a thread that always refresh the data from the server. In which place should I run that thread, and populate the interface

```
std::shared_ptr<IConnection> connection = mapserver.OpenConnection("WFS:http://192.168.139.129/cgi-bin/tinyows.exe");
    std::shared_ptr<IData> frida = connection->QueryLayer("frida");
    Areas *areas = new Areas(frida);

    vector<Area> areasVector = areas->getAreas();
```

Comment: Questions asking for [advice about code not yet written](http://meta.CodeReview.StackExchange.com/a/3651) are off-topic. Please [follow the tour](http://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/tour) and read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask), ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @BCdotWEB I have written the code. I would like to know how to work with these interfaces to solve my problem. For example how would I return an IConnection from OpenConnection(url). Is it ok to put a smart pointer or a normal pointer.

Comment: The part where you create and return the `IConnection` is not written yet, thus `OpenConnection` does not work as intended. Write the code, make it work, and then ask for a review; we'll point out what seems wrong.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger I have added the code.

Comment: I added the full code right now, waiting your feedback

Comment: I have edited the code with things, I hope someone give me a feedback